# Teradata triggers: two simple syntax questions

Tags: teradata

Don't seem to find a working example:

a) How can we CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE on table_name FOR ...

b) Is there a simple syntax to drop a table with defined triggers, and why would TD try to block it anyway?

Comment: a) you can't. b) no, triggers and join indexes must be dropped first.

Comment: @dnoeth, that's a double-negative

Comment: You can create 3 separate triggers; you can't have multiple triggering actions for one trigger.